# OS: Windows 8, problems with Xampp

Tags: windows

Can someone help me please? I would like to know how to use port 80. I deactivated IIS but the problem persists. When I write "localhost" in the browser it just goes to Google to look for what localhost means.

Answer (score 0):

Going to Google is a feature of your browser that can be turned off.

Go into the Settings or Tools-Options, as appropriate for your browser and disable searching from the address bar.